# Heroku, RabbitMQ and many workers. What is the best architecture?

Tags: heroku, rabbitmq

I am looking for the best approach to handle the following scenario:

I have multiple edge devices publishing sensor data to a RabbitMq broker. The broker will experience an overall workload of ~500 messages per seconds. Then there is a python worker dyno who consumes one sensor reading at a time, applies a filter on it (which can take up to 5-15ms) and publishes the result to another topic.

Of course one worker is not enough to serve all requests, so I need a proper scaling. I use a queue to make sure each sensor reading is consumed only once!

My questions are:

1. Do I scale horizontally and just start as many dynos as necessary to handle all requests in the RabbitMQ queue? Seems simple but more expensive.
2. Or would it be better to have less dynos but more threads running on each dyno, and using e.g. celery?
3. Or is there a load balancer that consumes 1 item out of the queue and schedules a dyno dynamically?
4. Something totally different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

option 1 or 2 are your best bets

i don't think option 3 exists without tying directly into the heroku API, and writing a ton of code for yourself... but that is overkill for your needs, IMO

between 1 & 2, the choice would depend on whether or not you want to grow the ability to handle more messages without re-deploying your code.

option 1 is generally my preference because i can just add a new dyno instance and be done. takes 10 seconds.

option 2 might work if you don't mind adjusting your code and redeploying. it will add extra time and effort for the tradeoff of cost.

but at some point, option 2 will need to turn into option 1 anyways, as you can only do so much work on a dyno to begin with. you will run into limitations on threads, with dynos. and then you'll be scaling out with dynos.

Comment: So it's no waste to have a single Dyno just executing a short term python process? Also at the moment RabbitMQ as a broker is responsible to manage the queue and to evenly distribute each message to the consumer so no consumer would receive the same message. So there is no need for a load balancer taking care of that right?

Comment: RabbitMQ takes care of load-balancing for you.  By having multiple consumers on the same queue/direct exchange, you get load balancing by default.  As far as a single Dyno just executing a short term python process, this is a worker continually consuming new messages for processing, so it will always be working unless I misunderstand your use case.

Comment: Yes you are right. I guess there is no need for Celery. I was just concerned that such a simple python process could be a waste of Dynos. In the end this approach might be easier to maintain but properly more expensive because of the needs of more Dynos running in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

It seems with GuvScale you can scale the workers consuming massages from RabbitMQ